# Cannot Set Status Code

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm using the basic `Response.StatusCode` to set the status code to 9999. This page is being called via an AJAX call, checking the status code on `readyState = 4` and popping an alert on 9999 using the message set by `Response.StatusDescription`. All I'm getting is `readyState = 4` and `statusCode = 200`. I can provide code if needed, but it's not trim, so I'll trim it down if the code is needed/requested. Any help is appreciated.Coded in C# ASP.NET and Javascript.

**UPDATE** *Purpose:* I'm suing the status code 9999 to denote a "User already exists" error when adding a user to an SQL table. This is the only way I can find to let the AJAX call know when this error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused - which numbers are C# and which JavaScript? You're sending 9999 from C# and seeing 200 in the JavaScript?

Comment: Why are you trying to override the HTTP status codes? They do have meaning you know.

Comment: @Rup Yes I'm sending 9999 from C# and getting 200 in JavaScript

Comment: @Oded Added the purpose to the original question

Comment: You couldn't add an `ErrorMessage` field to your JSON instead?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `409 Conflict`? http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10

Comment: @Oded Haven't used JSON before. If you have a link, I'd love to educate myself on it. that may be a better option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't make up status codes. [Here are the valid ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

I think the best option is to send back your status and message in a json response.

```
{
    status: 9999,
    message: "User already exists"
}
```

Here is a SO post with some links that might educate you on how to do this:
[Returning JSON object from an ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: I've never dealt with json before. I've added the purpose of my attempt above. Would json work for this and do you have a link to a good json tutorial or something i could educate myself with?

Comment: @steventnorris Sure thing! I've added a link that should help you out.

Comment: Ended up using a 409 status code for my purposes (path of least resistance), but I looked at the JSON and it's pretty neat. Would have worked just as well.