# Receiving json via ajax asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

My variable data in function ShowFavorits is undefined even do that my ajax call do return a json string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    ShowFavorits();

    function AjaxGet() {
        var param = "{'_userID': '1337'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/webservices/MinSide.asmx/GetFavorits",
            data: param,
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty("d")) {                      
                    return (data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //error
            }
        });
    }

    function ShowFavorits() {
        var data = AjaxGet();

        $("#addedList").html(
        $("#addedTemplate").render(data)
        );
    }
});
```

```
        [WebMethod]
    public string GetFavorits(string _userID)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jss.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        string JsonData = string.Empty;

        var db = new ModelDataContext();
        var list = db.table.Where(x => x.userID == _userID).OrderBy(x=> x.TimePin).ToList();

        JsonData = jss.Serialize(list);  
        return (JsonData);
    }
```

Why cant i return the result from my ajax?

Hope someone can help me, have been stuck for hours now debugging this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning JSON object from an ASP.NET page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$.ajax` in `AjaxGet` is asynchronous: the function returns undefined because the ajax call hasn't finished.

You should move the call to `ShowFavourits` into the ajax success function so that it executes once the ajax call is complete/successful

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Kick-off the ajax request
    AjaxGet();

    function AjaxGet() {
        var param = {_userID: '1337'};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/webservices/MinSide.asmx/GetFavorits",
            data: param,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty("d")) {                      
                    ShowFavorits(data.d); // Pass the data to the template
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function ShowFavorits(data) {
        $("#addedList").html(
            $("#addedTemplate").render(data)
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I now get the data to ShowFavorits() but its not working. If i hardcode the JSON from AjaxGet into ex var data2 and pass that to render then it works.

Comment: Then you need to focus on debugging the `GetFavorits` WebMethod: step it through a debugger and check that: you're getting data, it's being serialised properly, that the response is being sent correctly (right mime type, no extra data in response).

Also, you don't need to set `contentType` in ajax request. And turn that param into a proper object rather than a string e.g. {_userID: '1337'} (unless your method accepts and deserialises JSON strings - not clear from code sample)

Comment: If i return a List from my WebMethod instead of a string it works fine :)