# how to build json object using .net and out it in http request

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm building a mobile application that recive data from a server as json object , im using asp.net / sql server database to build the server , i dont know how to retrive data from sql database and convert it to json object that the client can request
I'm not using asp.net MVC
any help to start !

Comment: What sort of ASP.NET project are you building?  What entity is handling your incoming request right now - an aspx page? an HttpHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JSON.net](http://json.net). It is a JSON serialization framework that has also been adopted by ASP.NET MVC [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release). You can install it via [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet).

Comment: but after i create a json object , how i put it in alink so the client will request ??

Comment: You can stream it as a Response from any aspx-page. See the following link (the example uses DataContractJsonSerializer, an alternative to JSON.net). Especially the last part is important. http://petermcintyre.com/topics/asp-net-deliver-json/

Comment: then i can request this json object from my ios application ?? some one told me that you can't request json objects from ios app if the server was asp.net one -_- !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC you can create a controller that returns JSON. In your controller do:

```
return Json(yourObject);
```

You can also do it using the [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release). It will do content negotiation for you and return the data in the format you request it (JSON, XML, etc.).

Web API reference: *[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)*

Comment: how can i use web api ? any example to follow ?

Comment: Check it out here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: thanks alot :) but when i create ajson object how i will put it in alink that the client will request

Comment: [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx) walks you through adding WebAPI to a webforms project.  You set the route to use for a url to get to your controllers in Application_Start() as shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build some sort of web service that handles this request.

Here's a couple of options.

- You could use [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release) to write the service and use its automatic serialization / deserialization helpers
- You could also write up a class that implements IHttpHandler, parse the incoming request using a JSON deserializer library, and serialize a JSON response using the same serializer library. This might be simpler than using Web API, especially if you need to deal with query string parameters in a way that is odd when using the automatic parameter functionality in Web API.
- There is also a way to do this using [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), although it's even more complicated than the above.

Comment: thank u :)  , can you send me any link to follow the seconed choice ?

Comment: Also, please Google this for more details on how to wire this up in an application.  There are examples out there, but you need to look for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer class, for example:

```
SomeType obj = ....

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Then you should instruct browser to download json, here you can see: 
[Returning JSON object from an ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page)

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(json);
Response.End();
```

You can use other serializers too:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/133778/