# How Can i get the C# POST value in as3 without HTML tag?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

as3 POST Value to C#,and C# returns the Value

```
          Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("OK");
```

here is as3 code.

```
private function loader_onComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader=event.target as URLLoader;
        var processor:Object=loaderMap[loader];
        var dataStr:String = loader.data as String;
                    ...
             }
```

BUT the dataStr value is

> dataStr = OK
>
> !DOCTYPE html html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" (head)(meta
>   http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /)(title)

How can i get the value without HTML tag..Just "OK"..
thanks ...

Comment: Not exactly the same content type, but the same steps to solve: possible duplicate of [Returning JSON object from an ASP.NET page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: Note that if you can use ASP.Net MVC it would be much easier to generate non-HTML response (JsonResult or ContentResult).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank u for replying, I used webservice instead of aspx. it worked fine.