# $.getJSON ParseError

Tags: json, jquery

I'm using $.getJSON and I get this error "Invalid character".
My server side returns a good looking json, and in fiddler I think it also looks fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry i wanted to take a better picture. posting it again.

Comment: @raina77ow, What am I doing wrong that my Json is an xml?

Comment: I have this line in my C# server side: json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

Comment: One thing: you give some promise to your code - with `getJSON` - then break it. The code won't be able to magically 'guess' that it needs to extract JSON from some other source.

Comment: How is this `json` served in response?

Comment: The C# function return a string.

Comment: Is that string written into `Response` object, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page)?

Comment: No, just returning it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix of XML and JSON in your response.  This obviously does not work. It needs to be valid JSON only.

Comment: I don't know.  You haven't shared any code for where server generates the response.