# Converting any string to JSON format in C#

Tags: c#, json, string

I am using GET method (MCV4 / WEB-API/ VS 2010).

I want to return a response string in json format.

I have a string (any string) and want to convert it to json to be return as response).

How can I convert any string to JSON format:

```
string s = "{\"one\":\"a\", \"two\": \"2\"}";
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, <what shall i put here in order to return json of string s>);
```

Can I do something like this? :

```
string s = "{\"one\":\"a\", \"two\": \"2\"}";
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, s, "application/json");
```

I need to convert string, because I am using 3rd party tool, that send me string (and not json object).
I don't understand what wrong, because json represented actually a long string - it just called json.

I don't know whether the response add " sign, because I am cheking that on advanced rest client plugin for chrome, and I see " sign before and after the string. Nevertheless, string I pass, shall be with " sign before and after.

Thanks :)

Comment: check out [this stackoverflow post][1].
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't convert the object you plan to return to a particular format with Web API. The server will return the data in the requested format if it knows how, based on content negotiation. So your function signature should return a string, and Web API will take care of converting to XML or JSON as appropriate.

See [Web API Content Negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation).

Update, example function:

```
public string GetString()
     {
     string s="Hello, world!";
     return s;
     }
```

or

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetString()
    {
    string s="Hello, world!";
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, s);
    }
```

If you want to return a dictionary, then something like this:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> GetDict()
    {
    var dict=new Dictionary<string,string>();
    dict.Add("one", "a");
    dict.Add("two", "2");
    return dict;
    }
```

or

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetDict()
    {
    var dict=new Dictionary<string,string>();
    dict.Add("one", "a");
    dict.Add("two", "2");
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, dict);
    }
```

Comment: What you mean - I shall do: Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, s); with contents-type = application/json? What I see that response return null string.

Comment: I am using mcv4 as web-api, inherit apicontroller class like this: public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{    s = " ... "
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, s, "application/json"); but the above return a string (with " at start and at end, and not json).
}

Comment: @Eitan Try my updated code, particularly the last block. And no, do not specify the content type in your response. Let the framework handle that for you.

Comment: See my clarifications on your post.

Comment: I want to do something very generic (one code for all strings) - I just send json as string, and want to return as string (because the parser is elsewhere - not in C#).

Comment: @Eitan then see Unlimited's comment on your question. But I believe that will lead to a poor design. Let the framework work for you. Let it handle conversions to different content types instead of using custom parsers.

Comment: As I am using 3rd party tool which send me string,  I need to manipulate with string. For end-user: shall be json. So user do post/get json, but I am calling 3rd party tool, that return string, so I need to do some manipulation with c#. isn't there any json2str or str2json function? also - How do I get a json string (as a parameter - it can be of any kind of json, so I don't won't to write it again and again for each json format - Just one code.

Comment: @Eitan Like I said, you are going about this completely wrong if you think your service is just "manipulating strings". Your web service should accept an object as a parameter, that object's specifications should match the structure of the data you plan to receive. Then you should return that object after you have performed that manipulation on it. Notice that I did not mention anywhere about converting to or from JSON. Let the framework handle conversion and content negotiation as it's supposed to. When you write controllers with Web API, that is not your responsibility to handle.

Comment: @Eitan Your question is turning into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: OK. I accept what you say, but my code is an interface between two systems, so the parsing is not on the C# code, and not shall be (I don't have any code for both system) - I just by mistake pass a json string like {"one":"1"} instead of "{\"one\":\"1\"} in chrome  advanced rest client plugin. content-type is application/json - now things work. That's why I mistakenly understood that "json" is not a string, but if other system - it is always string, but the content-type is JSON. This issue can be closed.