# Asp.net Web Method Returns JSON

Tags: json

I need to create a **WebMethod** that returns my member database values on JSON. I try something like that but it actually failed.

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static UYELER handleAjaxRequest(string mailX, string passwordX)
{
    DataSet dsX = ReadSql("select top 3 * from fuyeler ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dsX.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        mailX = dsX.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stMail"].ToString();
        passwordX = dsX.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stPass"].ToString();
    }
    return new UYELER
    {
        mail = mailX,
        password = passwordX,
    };

}

public class UYELER
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Readsql is my quick sql connection class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return Json from an Asp.Net method by clearing the normal output in Page_Load and returning your own output.  See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page)...

To convert a C# object to JSON you can use a library such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: This looks fine i guess. Its return json data. Is it the same thing another json returns? Like global asax or ashx files or mvc's json returns? This one looks pretty easy compare to other ones.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1:

Add this to your `Application_Start` in Global.asax page:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;

        //....
    }
```

#### Method 2

You can alse decorate your method with ResponseFormat set JSON

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static UYELER handleAjaxRequest(string mailX, string passwordX)
{
    DataSet dsX = ReadSql("select top 3 * from fuyeler ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dsX.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        mailX = dsX.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stMail"].ToString();
        passwordX = dsX.Tables[0].Rows[i]["stPass"].ToString();
    }
    return new UYELER
    {
        mail = mailX,
        password = passwordX,
    };

}
```