# Http status code always returns as '204'

Tags: javascript, html

I have working to upload the file using below code.

```
var file = document.getElementById("file1") .files;  
for(var i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
   var formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("file1", file[i]);
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
   ajax.open("POST", "http://localhost:3006/api/RestAPI/Store");
   ajax.send(formdata);
   }
}
```

My server side action

```
  public void Store()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {
            var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["MyKey1"];

            if (httpPostedFile != null)
            {
                var fileSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyKey");
                if (!Directory.Exists(fileSave))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileSave);
                }
                var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(fileSave, httpPostedFile.FileName);
                httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i have upload my files, datas passed in to server side method properly. But even the file saved successfully or failed to upload,  i have received the http status code in client side **completeHandler** as '204' only. No changes in http status code. How to resolve it ?

Is any possibilities to change the status code value from server side and send to client side

Comment: Research _“how do I specify the HTTP status code using server side technology X”_ then …? (Since you failed to mention what server side technology X even _is_, that’s the best you can get for now.)

Comment: 204 means successful but no response. Unless your server side script is suppose to send some response, I don't think there is an issue here. Check your web-server or app server logs, in case your server side script is suppose to send a response.

Comment: Hi @gurvinder372, 
If i remove this line 'httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath)'  from the server side code. I receive the same 204 status only

Comment: Your server side action doesn't send anything back, apparently. After saving the file, you'll want to send an actual response to the client. Even though you're uploading a file, the client is still sending a *request* and expects a *response*.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, I am new in server handling. So can you please guide how to send the response to the client? Is any demo for that?

Comment: @Joy You could send back JSON like `{ "success": true }`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page

Comment: @ChrisG, Thanks for your help. I have fixed the issue by setting the content-type as below
        HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

you are sending

```
formdata.append("file1", file[i]);
```

but your webmethod doesnt have any parameter, that generates an error and the request gets cancelled.

Comment: The cause of the problem was already correctly identified by gurvinder 15 minutes ago. The problem is the missing response, since per OP's words, the file does get saved on the server.