# Record is added in to the database but alert message is not displayed using Asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Record added successfully.after add the record alert message should display record added success at ajex success function.but alert message isn't displayed i can see error on console. how to returning JSON result from the Page_Load
console show error

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>

    </title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="./insert.aspx" id="form1">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="zTrrqKI/DheoFwp4sc62RwzP0iY7axSftHzvJzZCC41CzVd9kYfD4XJIyas1nyNOAlwAs0DfeNlb18I4G2QbZ+NkGfH792zp/tKY3N+cROg=" />
    </div>

    <div class="aspNetHidden">

        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="F80457EB" />
    </div>
        <div>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Form Design of asp.net**

```
<form  id="frmProject" runat="server">
            <div>
                <label class="form-label">First Name</label>     
               <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control"  />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
             <label class="form-label">Age</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control"  />
            </div>
            <div> 
               <input type="button" id="b1" value="add" class="form-control" onclick="addProject()" />

            </div>
        </form>
```

**Ajax through send the data in to insert.aspx page**

```
   <script>
             function addProject() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'insert.aspx',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val()},
                success: function (data) {
                  alert("suceess");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        }     
    </script>
```

**insert.aspx page**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fname = Request.QueryString["fname"];
            string age = Request.QueryString["age"];
            string sql = "insert into record values('" + fname + "','" + age+ "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("success");
            con.Close();         
        }
```

Comment: Is your project properly set up to use the AutoEventWireup feature, as your code seems to suggest?

Comment: no error was displayed sir. i am new to Asp.net sir. when i show the database table automent increment id will  added as id-5    fname- no valued added      age  0

Comment: sir data is not send to the insert.aspx page  (fame,age ) i don't know why is that any ajex code wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Request.Form instead of Request.QueryString

```
string fname = Request.Form["fname"];
string age = Request.Form["age"];
```

Comment: thanks for you kind help it is working but ajex  success function alert msg is not displayed  alert("success");         success: function (data) {       
                    alert("success");
                },

Comment: if the data is added how to get back to index.aspx  ajex success funtion

Comment: Did you check on the "isNew" variable in your ajax call.

Comment: sir can you check the ajex code now success function . i need only alert message success only return

Comment: only   alert("suceess"); display

Comment: Please check your console for any errors in ajax call

Comment: console no error sir. record is added successfully. alert message is not displayed

Comment: I guess it's because you are not returning JSON result from the Page_Load. Try returning a valid JSON response from the server.

Comment: how to do the task sir please help me i am new to asp.net. how to returning JSON result

Comment: Please refer the below thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422983/returning-json-object-from-an-asp-net-page

Comment: if you write the code it is helpful for me sir thanks

Comment: Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            Response.Write(sql);
            Response.End();
            con.Close();         output i got at console insert into  record  raja  23